# Laravel : generate migrations from 2 MySQL databases

Tags: mysql, laravel

I've divided my database into 2 databases on MySQL and I'd like to generate migrations from both databases on laravel. 
I made all the configurations but when I execute the command "php artisan migrate:generate" it creates migrations only for the first database.
Does anyone know how to create the migrations of the 2 databases ?

Thanks for your help :)

My config/database.php file

```
'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC' ,
    ], 

'mysql2' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST_2', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT_2', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_2', 'forge1'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME_2', 'forge1'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD_2', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET_2', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => 'InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC' ,
    ],
```

My .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=evamesure
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=evamesure1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: I think that can generate conflicts is better if you want to change `database` better modify the `.env`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `migrate:generate`, then update your `DB_CONNECTION` env variable to `mysql2` and run it again.

Do not put duplicate keys in your .env file.  In your config file you suffixed `_2` to the second connection's env variables but you aren't using that suffix in .env.

---

If you want all environments to use two databases, you'll have to manually insert the connection name in the 2nd database's migrations and models.

Comment: Thanks I have created migrations for both databases. This means that in my .env and database.php  file I keep the connection only from one database ?

Comment: yeah if you want it all in one db going forward

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to migrate 2 database what you can do is this in your `.env`
run first migration with `php artisan migrate`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=evamesure
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

later when complete first `migration` update your `.env` to next `database` and run again `php artisan migrate`

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=evamesure1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about generating the migrations, but when you're writing your migrations, you are able to specify a connection that you want to run a migration on:

```
Schema::connection('mysql')->create('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // This table will only be created for the mysql connection
});

Schema::connection('mysql2')->create('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // This table will only be created for the mysql2 connection
});
```

That will allow you to have different tables for different databases. If you want to have the same tables in both databases, you could take the same approach:

```
foreach (['mysql', 'mysql2'] as $connection) {
    Schema::connection($connection)->create('your_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // Create a table for each database
    });
}
```

Don't forget that you will need to specify the relevant connection in your models if you want a certain model to use a non-default connection:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mysql2';
}
```